# search on 'id' which contains '/' + jquery

Tags: jquery

I have DOM elements whose id may contain '/' in it.
I want to use following formate, as I need all elements having the id
   for Ex:

```
jQuery('[id=activities/_terp_count]') //returns null
```

Note that ,

```
jQuery('#activities/_terp_count') //returns null
```

Comment: ID attributes cannot contain forward slashes. It's not surprising jQuery has a hard time finding such elements. That said, there might still be a way to get the element with that ID. Also, "all elements with that ID" Note that you should only have one such element.

Comment: An `id` "must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").". The `/` is an invalid character.

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html

Comment: but this FORMATE is the requirement of my project! If there is anyway.

Comment: Your first code works fine on Firefox 4, Safari 5 and IE 8 http://jsbin.com/ewexu

Comment: ohh. @kennyTM Thanks for the information. but I need compatibility in all possible working browsers

Comment: @Shanta: I believe it works for other browsers too, it's just that I have only checked these 3. (Checking for the rest is your job :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery('[id=activities/_terp_count]')` should indeed find it (example - http://jsfiddle.net/jXsvA/), although it's going to be slower than a direct search by ID. It'll be faster if you can limit the selector some way, such as `jQuery('div[id*=activities/_terp_count]')` if you know the tags are always `<div>`'s for example.

Comment: Your solution was helpful for me, but with quotes inside (around `id`): `jQuery('[id="activities/_terp_count"]')`. Without it I've got a `Syntax error, unrecognized expression...`.

Answer (score 7):

The above solution works for me, but it's worth noting that there are advantages to the native method of getting an element by id: that is, document.getElementById('strin/g') will work here in cases where jQuery("strin/g") will fail (because jQuery uses a token parser that chokes on "/" without special treatment.escaping).  To get the jQuery wrapped version of that element:

```
jQuery(document.getElementById('activities/_terp_count'));
```

In fact, if you can't always control exactly what's going into the actual id (say, if you're trying to search a page for an element with the id of something that was specified in the url #hash) then, a) be careful, because that can be dangerous and b) note that jQuery(document.getElementById(window.location.has.replace("#",''))); will work much more reliably than jQuery("#"+window.location.has.replace("#",'')); because it won't break as easily.

Example:

```
jQuery(document.getElementById("_=_")) //<--- null, or the actual element, if you have one which said crazy, non-compliant id

jQuery("#_=_") //<--Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #_=_
```

If you don't want your users to be able to break your code just by entering in a particular url parameter or hash, avoid that use case if you can, and if you can't, use the native ID element.

Comment: this is the simplest solution and the most sensible one. 
Why bothering [escaping](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) (that is always prone to errors in unexpected situations), when you can leverage that resposability to native javascript methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the normal ID selector if you escape the `/` sign - jQuery [requires that for special characters](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (though, `/` doesn't have a spacial meaning in jQuery or CSS, as far as I know)

```
$('#activities\\/_terp_count')
```